# rescind access to the document on OneDrive for business via REST API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, onedrive-for-business

I need to be able to programatically rescind access to a guest link for all external users that are given the link. Basically I need to programatically emulate the disable button like below. Preferably with the SharePoint 2013 REST API or SharePoint online REST API. Is this possible?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I did stumble across REST API call to retrieve the link - but nothing around disabling it.

```
<site URL>/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle(‘library name’)/items(item id)/GetObjectSharingInformation?$expand=SharedWithUsersCollection&retrieveAnonymousLinks=true
```

If you look at the button it's onclick

```
OnDisableLink(false, this, GetManageLinkParams());return false;
```

OnDisableLink is part of the $_global_sharing, which resides in sharing.js.  GetManageLinkParams() returns link info as well, but only seems to work within the context of the sharing page.

It's not an answer - but hopefully it may help get you closer or someone else may already have broken that JS file open and can supply the rest of the story.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get the properties on this SharedWithUserCollection. Some interesting properties are:

AnonymousEditLink
AnonymousViewLink
CanBeShared
CanBeUnshared
CanManagePermissions
HasPendingAccessRequests
HasPermissionLevels
IsSharedWithCurrentUser
IsSharedWithGuest
IsSharedWithMany
IsSharedWithSecurityGroup
PendingAccessRequestsLink
SharingLinks

I'm going to try setting IsSharedWithGuest to false in a POST or MERGE request.